# How to expand Map to extent of browser?

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api

Simple question on my Silverlight Application.  How can I expand the Map to full extent of browser no matter the size of the browser?

Answer (score 3):

use:

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <behaviors:WheelZoom />         
    <behaviors:MaintainExtentBehavior />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

http://serverapps.esri.com/samples/MaintainExtentBehavior.cs.txt
(MaintainExtentBehavior.cs)

http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/silverlightwpf/archive/2009/08/14/Using-Behaviors-to-enable-MouseWheel-in-Full-Screen-and-Out_2D00_of_2D00_browser.aspx#comments

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your map control covers all of the page as you are designing.

Next in your web application when your silverlight object is declared make sure that the width and height attributes are both 100%.

With that set, you map should fill the entire browser area no matter how large or small the browser.